# Ada - Nullable type

Tags: types, null, ada

How can I initialize a custom type to null ?

I want to do this :

```
TestVar : T_MyType := null;
```

With :

```
type T_MyType is
record
    field1 : float
    field2 : Boolean
end record
```

But I have an error :

> expected type "T_MyType" defined at myfile.ads

Comment: An useful information would be: for which purpose do you want a "null" there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can emulate nullable types using variant records:

```vhdl
    type T_MyType(Is_Null : Boolean := True) is 
       record
          case Is_Null is
             when False => 
                field1 : Float
                field2 : Boolean
             when True =>
                null; -- no parameters
          end case;
       end record

       -- Example "Null" value.  Trying to use field1 or field2 will
       -- result in an exception as they are not available when Is_Null
       -- is set to True
       Null_MyType : constant T_MyType := (Is_Null => True);
```

This type has no parameters by default (Is_Null is True by default).  For large types, you may have to be careful returning one of these as it might be expensive (you would need to see your compiler vendor to find out if it has optimization for this).

Comment: How do you test what the discriminant value was when the variable was created, such as `if Null_MyType.Is_Null then ...`?

Comment: @Patrick yes, that is one way.  If you prefer, you can also overload the "=" comparison operator so you can compare to Null_MyType.

Answer (score 6):

The only thing that can be *null* in Ada is an [access](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Types/access) which is the name for pointers.

In your case, you need to define what you expect when trying to assign *null* to your value. Sometimes, we define a kind of uninitialized value such as :

```vhdl
    null_value : constant T_MyType := T_MyType'(field1 => -1.0, field2 => False);
```

But if you really want to deal with a pointer as in C/C++, you need to declare the associated *access type* :

```vhdl
    type T_MyType_Access is access T_MyType;
```

With this, you'll be able to declare pointers to *T_MyType* objects.

Just one thing, compared to C/C++, in Ada, you usually can build entire applications without using *access types* (aka pointers).

Answer (score 2):

By default, Ada types are values types.

That is, TestVar is the object itself, with its contents field1, field2. You can imagine it at the place in the source code where you define it. It's not different than having a variable of a simpler type like Float.

In C# or similar languages, some types are "value types", but some others are "reference types". In the latter case, instead of the object itself, TestVar would be actually a pointer to the real object.

In your Ada code a value to be given to TestVar is, for instance, `(1.23, True)`.

If you really need pointers (be careful, you need them much less than you think, if you come from C, C++, C#, ...) you can define an access type.

Comment: I actually come from C# and I'm very new to Ada. I don't know how to use pointers in Ada, I'll do some research for that.

Comment: @A.Pissicat in C#, as in Java, AFAIK, everything is pointer, even though it's hidden. In Ada, as in C/C++, pointers are different from values (structs, class instances...). If you never used pointers before, this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f-pJlnpkLp0) might give you an idea of what it is. Then take a look at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming))